# ng-click or ng-submit is not invoking controller method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have just started learning Angular JS and downloaded [Dan Wahlin's Customer Manager App](https://github.com/DanWahlin/CustomerManagerStandard)
for my hands on. I have tried so far to call my Web API to return all records and bind with View which worked well.
Now I am trying to add a textbox with submit button to search for the entered text, which seems very basic functionality of angular app, but failing to invoke controller method by clicking the submit button:

```
    <form ng-submit="getSearchResuls(id)">
        <input type="text" data-ng-model="id" class=" novalidate form-control" />
        <input type="submit" value="Search"  />
    </form>
```

I have also tried:

```
        <form >
        <input type="text" data-ng-model="id" class=" novalidate form-control" />
        <input type="submit" value="Search" onclick="getSearchResuls(id)" />
    </form>
```

Both are not working with my following controller definition 
    (function () {

```
var injectParams = ['$location', '$filter', '$window',
                    '$timeout', 'authService', 'dataService', 'modalService'];

 var CustomersController = function ($location, $filter, $window,
    $timeout, authService, dataService, modalService) {

function getSearchResuls(id) {
        dataService.getSearchResults(id, vm.currentPage - 1, vm.pageSize)
            .then(function (data) {
                vm.totalRecords = data.totalRecords;
                vm.customers = data.results;
                filterCustomers(''); //Trigger initial filter

                $timeout(function () {
                    vm.cardAnimationClass = ''; //Turn off animation since it won't keep up with filtering
                }, 1000);

            }, function (error) {
                $window.alert('Sorry, an error occurred: ' + error.data.message);
            });
    }
};

CustomersController.$inject = injectParams;

angular.module('customersApp').controller('CustomersController', CustomersController);

}());
```

I have also tried to add **ng-controller** in **form** tag but still with no luck.
Can I have your valuable remarks to solve this issue please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `getSearchResuls` needs to be added to your scope. So, first off, make sure that '$scope' is listed as an injectParams, and then include $scope as an argument for your CustomersController. Then do something like this:

```
$scope.getSearchResuls = function (id) {
   //the rest of your code here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I injected '$scope' in my controller then included it my controller like **var CustomersController = function ($scope,$location, $filter, $window,
        $timeout, authService, dataService, modalService) {** and then defined getSearchResuls method but I got error **ReferenceError: getSearchResuls is not defined** , any clues?

Comment: I went ahead and made a jsfiddle. I suspect that there might be other errors with your code. Feel free to provide another jsFiddle that I can take a better look at all of your code. http://jsfiddle.net/gsmk6f1w/

Comment: thanks for the JsFiddle link, I was messing with scope and **this** also a silly mistake was there, used onClick rather ng-Click, forgive me for that!

Comment: Now new problem is I want to access scope variable $scope.customers = data.results in view. I tried to access it like
 <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3" ng-class="vm.cardAnimationClass" ng-repeat="customer in customers>
But not working.

Comment: Glad to see that ngClick is working. Please create a jsfiddle, if possible. I noticed you are missing a double quote and possibly something else, but I cannot tell from the excerpt provided.